# Postman:could not send request

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I got this error from Postman:
Could not send request. CORS Error: The request has been blocked because of the CORS policy.

my code is as simple as:

```
app.get('/',(req,res) => {
  res.send('Hi')
});
```

It works fine on terminal but gets err from postman, does anyone know how to solve it??

Comment: make sure that u have hosted the app in the same port in which u are requesting on postman.

Comment: yes, the port is 3000

Answer (score 1):

Just figure it out from other post.

Install the npm package "cors", require and apply it:

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
```